# Salesforce CTI + IVR Integration Tools for Indian Numbers

Tags: cti, softphone, phone

We are looking for a CTI + IVR integration App, which supports Indian phone/mobile numbers. We would like to use the app in Salesforce service cloud.

**Questions:**
Please suggest few 3rd Party Apps (AppExchange) apps, which integrates with Indian Phone numbers?  Your answer will help us to evaluate various apps and based on that we can decide which app fits our use case.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you contacted the vendors listed in the AppExchange?